# Angular 5 reactive form- updating formControl through the html does not update the value, only the control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have a service with a FormGroup named mainForm-

```
export class DepositFormDataService{

  this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],
            category: '',
            type: '',
            languages: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        });
    }

    get title(): FormControl{
        return this.mainForm.get('title') as FormControl;
    }
}
```

In a component I use this service-

```
 constructor(public depositFormDataService: DepositFormDataService) {}
```

HTML:

```
 <input matInput [formControl]="depositFormDataService.title">
```

When the user writes "b" for example I see in the debug a difference if I look on the FormGroup depositFormDataService.mainForm:

in: Controls --> title --> value = b

in: value --> title --> null

Why?

I found this post in git-
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13792

I tries to do this hack in the component-

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.onChanges();
}

onChanges(): void {
    this.depositFormDataService.title.valueChanges
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.titleDestroy))
        .subscribe(value => {
            this.depositFormDataService.mainForm.get('title').patchValue(value, {emitEvent: false});
}
```

But it did not work and the value was still "null".

Any idea how to make the value be sync with the value inside the controls?

It causes a strange problem that depositFormDataService.mainForm.status differs from the depositFormDataService.title.status.

Comment: Try `this.mainForm.controls['title']` to get the control and `this.mainForm.controls['title'].value` to get the value

Comment: But the problem that I want them to be the same value, not different!

Comment: Can you put the entire html. There is some problem with the `formcontrolname` it seems

Comment: which problem? this is the important section in the html..

Answer (score 0):

I think In the HTML you should use formControlName instead of formcontrol like this:

```
<input  formControlName="title" matInput >
```

Comment: well, the difference is, the .ts form contains the form controls and angular looking for the matching names
form your code:
 this.mainForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            title: ['', Validators.required],   //its a control, with a name, value and validator
            category: '',
            type: '',
            languages: this.formBuilder.array([]),
        });

Comment: yes, I know, but I thought that the behavior will be the same. the exact thing should happens in both syntax, am I wrong?

Comment: no its not the same, its like an object and an object property, name. its not the same even the object only have one property.